# Facetime Unknown Caller late at night

Tags: privacy

I received a facetime call from an unknown caller...they called me at 10:30 pm (nighttime)...I did not know the caller...I do not know how they received my number...I was shocked to see that the unknown people could see me in my home late at night through my phone...it showed their number, but I didn't know the number...I have no idea who the strange caller was...I'm very uncomfortable that anyone could call me at anytime and see me/my home that easily...This is scary and feels dangerous to me....how do I prevent this from happening...this violates privacy...

Comment: Don’t answer it.

Answer (score 3):

The fact there were no details available to you (beyond the fact you could see their number) simply means they're not in your contacts - it doesn't necessarily mean the caller was unknown to you.

As for how they "received your number", well, anyone can call any random number and potentially it'll belong to someone. That is nothing new and has been going on for decades. Likewise with emails - I get emails from unknown people all the time. It doesn't mean they 'know' me and my email address.

It's no different for FaceTime. A caller could try their luck and FaceTime a random number or a random email address and if they belong to an iPhone user or to an Apple ID, well, the FaceTime call comes through.

So, if you don't want an incoming FaceTime video caller to potentially see you (or your home, etc) then the best option is simply not to answer it. If it turns out to be someone you know, they'll try you again later.

However, you can silence unknown callers to your iPhone's cell number. for more info on this and other options for avoiding unwanted calls to your cell number, refer to [Avoid unwanted calls on iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/iphone/iphe4b3f7823/ios) on Apple's website.

You can also [block unwanted callers in FaceTime on iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/iphone/iphcd8d3c813/ios) (but this is not the same as 'unknown' callers).

Comment: You could also consider setting Do Not Disturb automatically overnight. I don't mind answering unknown callers during the day (my job needs this) but at night they can go suck a lemon;)

Comment: Great info...I know it was a prank caller....I appreciate your advice....thank you!